# insert a video in beamer

Tags: beamer

If this rather trivial I apologize.
How we can embed very quickly a video (mp4) in a beamer slide?
From what I have seen I cannot figure out the proper way.

I tried with the multimedia package (following this [link](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/creez-vos-diaporamas-en-latex-avec-beamer/le-multimedia-1)) but it din't work.
(The slides will be in pdf format. I use Adobe reader XI.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{myvideo}
\movie[]{}{video.mp4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a stupid question: Have you tried with `video.mp4`?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. During copy-paste 4 was somehow changed to 3:-)! I have tried with mp4 and it does not work. Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: As well as the `\end{frame}`?

Comment: I just tried and got an error message from adobe that `mp4` is not a supported file type. As alternatives it let me choose files from the `avi` type. Can you try with such a movie?

Comment: As soon as I try I will tell you about the outcome. Thanks once again! You are right about \end{frame}. I should have created from the very begining a minimum example rather than adding commands.

Comment: I am already happy, that your example include the documentclass and packages, far from granted :) If this does not help, you could use alternative packages, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=.mp4